# jQuery UI dialog with multi-checkbox select. Can't save the post array for a multi-select until dialog has been triggered

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

#### HTML

```
<td class="cell">
    <a class="opener"
       id="opener_'.$iterator.'"
       href="#"
       rel="#type_dialog_<?= $iterator; ?>">Select</a>
    <div id="type_dialog_<?= $iterator; ?>"
         name="type"
         class="dialog"
         style="display:none">
```

#### jQuery code

```
$('.dialog').bind('dialogclose', function(event, ui) {
    $(this).closest('div.ui-dialog').appendTo('#mlsForm');
});

$('.opener').click(function(event) {
    $(".dialog").dialog("close");
    var top = $(event.target).offset().top + 15;
    var left = $(event.target).offset().left;
    $( ".dialog" ).dialog( "option", "position", [left, top] );
    $(event.target.rel).dialog("open");
    return false;
});
```

The problem is, unless the user clicks "Select", my update query receives an empty POST array! I checked, and it's not being set. The PHP runs to populate the existing "checked" checkboxes, but I cannot get it to save existing checkboxes without the user first clicking "Select" to trigger the dialog.

To clarify, the select data exists below the dialog `div` and works as follows:

```
$input_name = "listing[$iterator][ptid][]";
if (!empty ($numptc1)) {
    $tbl_links .= "<td><label><input type='checkbox' name='".$input_name."' value='".$ptid[$i]."' checked />$ptname[$i]</label></td>\n";
}
else {
    $tbl_links .= "<td><label><input type='checkbox' name='".$input_name."' value='".$ptid[$i]."' />$ptname[$i]</label></td>\n";
}
```

When the dialog has been triggered, I get an array as expected, but not otherwise:

```
[ptid] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
        [1] => 30
        [2] => 18
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) the click event after the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.opener').trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This has caused it to correctly handle the post data by default, but now the Select trigger isn't working. 

Your suggestion seems like it would fix just about every remaining problem I have, but I'm not sure how to get it to work after the initial trigger.

Comment: why its not working? remove the `ruturn false` and try it again.

Comment: ok, tried this and several variations of calling the function. unfortunately this causes the rest of the jquery below it to not work (keytables, etc) no matter how I try it.

any idea why this may be?